# Error when i try make HttpContext.Session.Set

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I got one error and i try make this:

`HttpContext.Session.Set<User>("user", who);`

I got this error:

> The non-generic method 'ISession.Set(string, byte[]) cannot be used
> with type arguments

I have one class `User` and `who` have all information about User.
The error is `.Set<User>`

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core does not let you store random objects in the session. You can only store byte arrays.

[ISession.Set(String, Byte[]) Method (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.isession.set)

There are extension methods to store and retrieve [a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.setstring?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-sessionextensions-setstring(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-isession-system-string-system-string)) or [an int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.setint32?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-sessionextensions-setint32(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-isession-system-string-system-int32)). But there are no methods to store instances of a class.

[Set and get Session values - Session in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-and-get-session-values)

The simplest option is to serialize your object to JSON and store the JSON string in the session. But there are complexities to consider, as [discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35993415/asp-net-5-core-how-to-store-objects-in-session-cache-isession).

```
Session.SetString("user", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(who));
User who2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(Session.GetString("user"));
```

Comment: SerializeObject(who), its ok perfect, and result!

But this: "User who2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(Session.GetString("user"));"

I got error like : "The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: If i try put HttpContext before .Session.GetString

I got error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session'

Comment: For [a Razor page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage), use `Context.Session`. For [an MVC controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase), use `HttpContext.Session`.

Comment: Razor page.. got the same error

Comment: Are you trying to call `Context.Session.GetString` from a `static` method or property?

Comment: Method where i try make deserialize 

 public static async void UserLog(string coisas, string datalink)
        {
User who = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User(HttpContext.Session.GetString("user")); ;

Class User is static too

Comment: @Marco Is the method where you are trying to deserialize marked as `static`? If so, you won't be able to access instance members of the page from that method.

Comment: Yes, is static method

Comment: Then you'll either need to make it an instance method, or pass in the `HttpContext` instance when you call it - the `HttpContext.Current` property was removed in ASP.NET Core.